# Localization format date and number precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

is there a way to use helper in yml file?
I have this:

*en.yml*

`n_buy_credits: "foo %{time}. Number %{number}."`

I'd like to show the %{time} parameter whit this format ("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M") and the %{number} with 2 levels of precision. Is it possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use I18n.localize helper:

```
<%= t('n_buy_credits', time: I18n.l(Time.now), number: l(1234)) %>
```

You can set format in your en.yml file:

https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-US.yml#L33
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-US.yml#L140